# Validate a property value against another property value

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Take the following schema:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "StageHEP": { 
      "description": "The stage of hepatitis",
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["ACUTE", "CHRONIC", "UNK"]
    },
    "complications": {
      "description": "Disease complications", 
      "type": "string",
      "enum: ["CIRR", "CANCER", "NONE", "UNK"]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to create a validation rule (within the schema) that states that:

> if `StageHEP = ACUTE`,  `complications` property cannot be `CIRR`

Is it possible with json-schema draft v4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using ["oneOf"](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/anyOf,-allOf,-oneOf,-not):

```
{
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "StageHEP": {
          "description": "The stage of hepatitis",
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "CHRONIC",
            "UNK"
          ]
        },
        "complications": {
          "description": "Disease complications",
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "CIRR",
            "CANCER",
            "NONE",
            "UNK"
          ]
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "StageHEP": {
          "description": "The stage of hepatitis",
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "ACUTE"
          ]
        },
        "complications": {
          "description": "Disease complications",
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "CANCER",
            "NONE",
            "UNK"
          ]
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```